# Upgrading to an Angular/AngularJS hybrid application: getting typescript errors / AngularJS import errors

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript, upgrade, angular-hybrid

We are in the process of upgrading an AngularJS application to Angular with the incremental approach: we would like to be able to create new components in Angular and upgrade existing AngularJS components one by one, all this still with a functional application during the process.

We use the [official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/upgrade) as well as several articles about hybrid Angular/AngularJS applications on real world applications.

Here are our attempts and the errors we get.

**Context**

- AngularJS 1.7.3
- Angular 6.1.7
- Typescript 2.7.2
- angular-cli

**First steps**

- upgrade to AngularJS 1.7
- remove Grunt and use angular-cli
- use ngUpgrade (app.module.ts and app.module.ajs.ts)

---

**Moving to Typscript: dealing with errors**

That's the official process: rename .js files to .ts.

We then moved from Node *require()* to TypeScript module loading (`var ... = require` --> `import ... = require`)

Ideally, we should correct all the typing errors due to using the TypeScript compiler.

But the [TypeScript doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/migrating-from-javascript.html) states that's it's possible to do an incremental migration: being **tolerant to TypeScript errors** at the beginning in order to compile the js code without modifications (and stricter later on after fixing the code).

To achieve this, we used the *awesome-typescript-loader* instead of tsc to get theses options: *transpileOnly*, *errorsAsWarnings* (this requires the use of *angular-builders/custom-webpack*).

The options allow to pass the compilation, but it appears that the **compilation is done twice**: first without errors (warnings or not), but second with errors... so the build fails. How can we run only the first compilation?

---

**Alternative attempt: keeping .js files, errors in importing and bootstrapping**

We tried also an unofficial and unusual way to migrate the js code incrementally, that is keeping the original .js files alongside new .ts files.

We got some errors at compilation or application loading, related to importing AngularJS and to module management. Indeed the [TypsScript module documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html) states that:

`Some libraries are designed to be used in many module loaders, or with no module loading (global variables). These are known as UMD modules. These libraries can be accessed through either an import or a global variable.` ... `can be used as a global variable, but only inside of a script. (A script is a file with no imports or exports.)`

What we noticed:

- in .js files: access to the **AngularJS global *angular*** (if we remove *require("angular")*) - **script mode**
- in .ts files: we can't use *import from angular*, otherwise we get the error `angular.module is undefined` - **module mode**

With this in mind, we made the application compile and load in the browser without errors, but at the end:

*this.upgrade.bootstrap(document.body, [App])*

generates an error on AngularJS bootstrapping:

**`Angular 1.x not loaded !`**

How to fix this? It may be because we didn't import AngularJS in the TypeScript module way to avoid the previous error?

The official documentation mentions *angular.IAngularStatic* (still get an error)?

We can try also *setAngularJSGlobal()* ? `Used when AngularJS is loaded lazily, and not available on window`

By the way what is the difference between using [App] or ["App"] when calling bootstrap()?

... Since we are new to this upgrade process, we may be doing completely wrong things. Thank you for sharing your experience!

---

**Configuration files**

**angular.json**

```
{
    "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
    "version": 1,
    "newProjectRoot": "acd-banner-multicanal",
    "projects": {
        "acd-banner-multicanal": {
            "root": "",
            "sourceRoot": "src",
            "projectType": "application",
            "architect": {
                "build": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
                    "options": {
                        "outputPath": "target",
                        "index": "src/index.html",
                        "main": "src/main.ts",
                        "tsConfig": "./tsconfig.json",
                        "assets": [
                            "src/i18n",
                            "src/conf/conf.txt",
                            "src/conf/conf_DEFAULT.txt",
                            "src/systemjs.config.js",
                            { "glob": "font-banner*", "input": "./node_modules/elq-font-icon/build/", "output": "/assets/fonts" },
                            "src/assets/images",
                            { "glob": "system.js*", "input": "./node_modules/systemjs/dist/", "output": "/assets" },
                            "src/assets/images",
                            { "glob": "**/*", "input": "./node_modules/tinymce/plugins", "output": "/assets/tinymce/plugins" },
                            { "glob": "**/*", "input": "./node_modules/tinymce/skins", "output": "/assets/tinymce/skins" }

                        ],
                        "styles": [
                            "src/assets/styles/style.less"
                        ],
                        "scripts": [
                            "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
                            "./node_modules/jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui.js"
                        ]
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "fileReplacements": [
                                {
                                    "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                                    "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                                }
                            ],
                            "optimization": true,
                            "aot": true,
                            "buildOptimizer": true
                        }
                    }
                },
                "test": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
                    "options": {
                        "main": "src/test.ts",
                        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
                        "karmaConfig": "./karma.conf.js",
                        "scripts": [],
                        "styles": [
                            "src/assets/main.less"
                        ],
                        "assets": [
                            "src/i18n",
                            "src/favicon.ico"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "lint": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
                    "options": {
                        "tsConfig": [
                            "tsconfig.json",
                            "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
                        ],
                        "exclude": [
                            "**/node_modules/**"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "acd-ihm-angular-e2e": {
            "root": "e2e/",
            "sourceRoot": "e2e",
            "projectType": "application",
        }
    },
    "defaultProject": "acd-banner-multicanal",
    "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
            "styleext": "less",
            "lintFix": true
        }
    }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "outDir": "./target",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "allowJs": true,
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "lib": [
            "es2017",
            "dom"
        ],
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
        "paths": {
            "angular": ["node_modules/angular/angular"]
        }
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
                "src/**/*.spec.ts"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As for the **`angular 1.x not loaded`** error;
Did you install angularJS in the new application?

```
$ npm install --save angular@1.7.3 \
      @types/angular
```

In the `angular.json` file you need to include the script:

```
"scripts": [
    "../node_modules/angular/angular.js",
    //etc...
],
```

[Here](https://joelbinn.gitbooks.io/hybrid-angular-angularjs-application-with-angular/content/ch1-making-the-hybrid.html)'s an example of upgrading an application that seem similar to what you have.

Alternatively you can bring in angular into the import chain by importing it in `main.ts`;

```
import * as angular from 'angular';
```

This might be a better option since it makes angular cli / webpack aware of angularJS and may prevent errors such as "`WARNING: Tried to Load Angular More Than Once`" that may arise if some other component (such as the hybrid router imports angular).

Comment: Indeed, adding `angular.js` to `angular.json` corrects the `angular undefined` and `Angular 1.x not loaded` errors. I'm going to continue the process, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I confirm that the answer works, we've been able to run our application in hybrid mode. In fact, in AngularJs, we used grunt and browserify, and we had packaged some libraries using the `package.json browser` field. To do the same, we had to **declare the libraries to load in the browser in `angular.js / build.options.scripts`**:

```
"scripts": [
    "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
    "./node_modules/jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui.js",
    "./node_modules/moment/moment.js",
    "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
    "./node_modules/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/src/js/bootstrap- datetimepicker.js",
    "./node_modules/bootstrap-tour/build/js/bootstrap-tour.js",
    "./node_modules/angular/angular.js",
    "./node_modules/ng-table/bundles/ng-table.js"`
]
```

Thanks a lot.

That may be useful to add in the Angular documentation? Indeed, the examples given in https://angular.io/guide/upgrade#bootstrapping-hybrid-applications are based on SystemJS, whereas we just use Webpack (already used by Angular).

Indeed, there is an [issue about the angular doc](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/30249), the migration doc is not yet updated for angular-cli (that's why it is about SystemJS).